# can a husband stay with his 4 wives under one roof?

Tags: polygamy

Is it permissible for a husband to live with his 4 wives in one home

With each wife having a room for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Each wife has the right to a separate house. This does not mean a separate building rather it means that there must be separate facilities such as bedroom, kitchen, bathroom etc. which can be locked and whose access is under the independent control of each wife.

Otherwise living in one house is conditional to the wife's consent, since it is her right she can waive it if she wants.

Comment: Ref: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/7653/